# Push values to the left, replace NAs with zeros

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this kind of data.frame

```
mydata <- data.frame(matrix(seq(20*3), 5, 6)) 
mydata[1,1:3] <-  NA 
mydata[2,1:1] <-  NA 
mydata[2,4] <-  NA 
mydata[3,1:3] <-  NA 
mydata[3,5:6] <-  NA 
mydata[4,2:4] <-  NA 
mydata[5,1:2] <-  NA
```

That looks like this:

```
UserID    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6
1         NA    NA    NA    16    21    26
2         NA    7     12    NA    22    27 
3         NA    NA    NA    18    NA    NA
4         4     NA    NA    NA    24    29
5         NA    NA    15    20    25    30
```

I would like to run some code that locates the first non NA value, and pushes the sequence back from there, and replaces all NA with 0. so the data is going to look like this:

```
UserID    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6
1         16    21    26     0     0     0
2         7     12     0    22    27     0
3         18     0     0     0     0     0
4         4      0     0     0    24    29
5         15    20    25    30     0     0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` to loop over the rows, identify the index of first non-NA value ('i1'), get the values from that index to the end of the vector, concatenate the rest with NA, `replace` the `NA` with 0, transpose the output and assign it back to the dataset.

```
mydata[-1] <-  t(apply(mydata[-1], 1, function(x) {
                      i1 <- which(!is.na(x))[1]
                      x1 <- c(x[i1:length(x)], rep(NA, i1-1))
                      replace(x1, is.na(x1), 0)
                }))
mydata
#  UserID X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
#1      1 16 21 26  0  0  0
#2      2  7 12  0 22 27  0
#3      3 18  0  0  0  0  0
#4      4  4  0  0  0 24 29
#5      5 15 20 25 30  0  0
```

#### data

```
mydata <- cbind(UserID=1:5, mydata)
```